# ubuntu 15.04 Ethernet is not working

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.04, ethernet

I recently got a new PC (specs will be shown below). Installation gave me no problem except Ubuntu can not connect to the internet. By the way i am very new to linux.

$ lspci -knn |grep -EA2 'Eth|net' output:

```
0e:00.0 ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros device [1969:e0a1] (rev10)
subsystem: Gigabyte technology Co. , Ltd Device [1458:e000]
0f:00.0 ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros device [1969:e0a1 (rev10)
subsystem: Gigabyte technology Co. , Ltd Device [1458:e000]
10.00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: intel corporation device [8086:1578] (rev 03)
```

I have 2 ethernet ports : Qualcomm Atheros killer E2400
And I have a wifi card: Killer Wireless-AC 1535

Again: I DO NOT HAVE ANY INTERNET ACCESS ON MY DESKTOP

My PC's specifications:

```
Motherboard: Gigabyte z170x Gaming G1
Graphics: MSI GeForce GTX 980 TI
RAM: 16GB Corsair DDR 4 (2x8 GB)
SSD: Samsung M.2
HDD: Western Digital 1 TB
SPS: Corsair 1000i
CPU: Skylake i7-6700K (4Ghz quad-core)
CPU Cooler: Cooler master
```

Comment: i haven't tested it but try `sudo modprobe alx ; echo -n 1969 e0a1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/alx/new_id`. according to http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux/21-killer-e2400-in-linux-ubuntu-debian `alx` supports your card

Answer (score 0):

It would be tedious and lengthy to patch the module *alx* without any form of internet connectivity. On the other hand, *alx* covers your device in the version included in Ubuntu 15.10:

```
$ modinfo alx
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
srcversion:     25B6ABE36E6CB50C1A7E6DF
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E0A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

As you can see, 1969:e0a1 is listed. I suggest you install the beta 2 version of 15.10: http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/

Comment: Is there any stability in that version?

Comment: I have had it installed for a few days now and have not had a single problem. Of course, that doesn't mean there aren't any, but my experience has been perfect.